# Shorter way to remove non-characters than gsub(/\d|\W/, "")

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub, string-substitution

```
my_string = 'Here's the #: 49848! - but will dashes, commas & stars (*) show?'

puts src.gsub(/\d|\W/, "")
```

i.e. can I remove the or ("|").

Here's how I got here, can I get shorter?

```
src =  "Here's the #: 49848! - but will dashes, commas & stars (*) show?"
puts "A) - " + src
puts "B) - " + src.gsub(/\d\s?/, "")
puts "C) - " + src.gsub(/\W\s?/, "")
puts "D) - " + src.gsub(/\d|\W\s?/, "")
puts "E) - " + src.gsub(/\d|\W/, "")
puts "F) - " + src

A) - Here's the #: 49848! - but will dashes, commas & stars (*) show?
B) - Here's the #: ! - but will dashes, commas & stars (*) show?
C) - Heresthe49848butwilldashescommasstarsshow
D) - Heresthebutwilldashescommasstarsshow
E) - Heresthebutwilldashescommasstarsshow
F) - Here's the #: 49848! - but will dashes, commas & stars (*) show?
```

n.d. D) and E) are what I want for output.  Just characters.

Comment: That's already pretty short. Are you trying to carve this code in stone or what? :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
my_string = "Here's the #: 49848! - but will dashes, commas & stars (*) show?"
p my_string.delete('^a-zA-Z')
#=>"Heresthebutwilldashescommasstarsshow"
```

Comment: Yeah this is best.  was trying to do this before but didn't know about the delete option.  Damn that's handy!

Answer (score 4):

I have this one

```
src.gsub(/[^a-z]/i, "")
```

also not shorter, but better to read in my opinion.

The `i` modifier makes the regex case independent, so that `a-z` matches also `A-Z`. A small difference is that this regex will also replace `_` which is not replaced by yours.

Comment: +1 good to know there's an underscore option as there could be cases both ways ! :)

Comment: The problem with this syntax is, it also removes 'spaces', so all the words in the sentece will be concatenated together like, 'thisismycomment'

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep also unicode letters, use this one:

```
/\PL/
```

This matches all non letter character.